# SMTP command stuck in cmd prompt

Tags: python

> I have installed Python 2.7 in widows 7. 
>   I am trying a basic smtp python program to automatically send mail through python script.
>   But when I am running the script through cmd prompt, it is just stuck indefinitely.

```
# Python code to illustrate Sending mail  
# to multiple users  
# from your Gmail account  
import smtplib 

# list of email_id to send the mail 
li = ["ishank4@gmail.com"] 

for i in range(len(li)): 
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
    s.starttls() 
    s.login("mymailid@gmail.com", "mypassword") 
    message = "Message_you_need_`enter code here`to_send"
    s.sendmail("sender_email_id", li[i], message) 
    s.quit()*
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def connect():
    while True:
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
        except smtplib.SMTPException as error:
            print(error)
            continue
        try:
            server.ehlo()
            if server.has_extn("starttls"):
                server.starttls()
                server.ehlo()
        except (smtplib.SMTPException,ssl.SSLError) as error:
            print(error)
            disconnect(server)
            continue
        break
    return server

def disconnect(server):
    try:
        server.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: I added some print statements to check where it is struck.

Comment: Looks like it is not coming out of the connect() function itself and is stuck there.

Comment: To be precise , the code is stuck at Line: server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")